# Issue with UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I need edit my Images before they import to the app but after editing the image reduces some quality how can avoid this ?

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imgEdited.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];


}
```

Comment: Did you find how to solve the problem of reducing the quality of images after edit them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
                      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  [picker release];

          // Edited image works great (if you allowed editing)
  myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
          // AND the original image works great
  myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
          // AND do whatever you want with it, (NSDictionary *)info is fine now
  UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}
```

You can edit ur image. Try this it may work for your application.Thanks!

Comment: thanks but does not solve my problem ! I think you did not understand my question

Answer (score 4):

You can crop `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` manually by using the value provided via  `UIImagePickerControllerCropRect`.

Untested quick and dirty example:

```
static UIImage *my_croppedImage(UIImage *image, CGRect cropRect)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cropRect.size);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-cropRect.origin.x, -cropRect.origin.y)];
    UIImage *cropped = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return cropped;
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // …

    UIImage *originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    CGRect cropRect = [info[UIImagePickerControllerCropRect] CGRectValue];
    UIImage *croppedImage = my_croppedImage(originalImage, cropRect);

    // …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lowering of quality does not have anything to do with the code you have presented above. The quality of the image depends on what you are doing with your image during editing. Are you zooming in and cropping the image?

Comment: without any cropping or zooming the result is same !

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is going to sound daft. But is the image really low quality or is it just being displayed as low quality?

You may want to export this image to your PC and check its actually low quality rather than just the imageview showing it as low quality.